# Setting For loop in Range without the end number

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping, range

I am working on a web-scraping code, which needs to scrape multiple websites. I used Selenium web-driver to do that and I use find_element_by_xpath to extract the information that I want. Here is my code

```
op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=op)
driver.get(web)
content1 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('k-master-row')


for c1 in content1:

    for i in range(1,401):

        amount1 = i


        try:
            caseid = c1.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="CasesGrid"]/table/tbody/tr[{}]/td[2]/a'.format(amount1)).text.strip()
            case_id.append(caseid)          
        except:
            pass

        try:
            style = c1.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="CasesGrid"]/table/tbody/tr[{}]/td[3]/div'.format(amount1)).text.strip()
            defendant.append(style)
        except:
            defendant.append('')
```

The code works perfectly fine but for the range, I have to maually set it everytime when I scrape different URLs. `//*[@id="CasesGrid"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a` This is the xpath, which are identical across all the URLs that I need to scrape. The only thing different is the `tr[1]`, it can range from 1 to 500 or 600. If the wbesite that I scrape start from 1 to 35, then I have to manually change the range to(1,35). I think this is very time consuming when I scrape a new URLs. I am wondering are there any better ways to set the range, so it will just stop whichever URLs that I scrape, thus I dont need to manually search the xpath to find the end number for the range.

Thank you all!!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to convey. Are you trying to `break` out of the loop when your xpath matches an element?

Comment: Can you iterate over the rows by fetching them via `find_elements_by_xpath()`?

Comment: @13.37f I am trying to find a better way to set the range so that I dont have to manually check the xpath number, whenever I scrape the websites

Comment: @JonSG I tried that before but it wasnt working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an infinite loop, and break out when you reach the end.

```
amount1 = 1
while True:
    try:
        tr = c1.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="CasesGrid"]/table/tbody/tr[{amount1}]')
    except:
        break

    try:
        caseid = c1.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="CasesGrid"]/table/tbody/tr[{}]/td[2]/a'.format(amount1)).text.strip()
        case_id.append(caseid)          
    except:
        pass

    try:
        style = c1.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="CasesGrid"]/table/tbody/tr[{}]/td[3]/div'.format(amount1)).text.strip()
        defendant.append(style)
    except:
        defendant.append('')

    amount1 += 1
```